# what's the equivalent of jscs `disallowKeywordsOnNewLine` in eslint?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, jshint, eslint, jscs

what's the equivalent of `jscs`'s `disallowKeywordsOnNewLine` in `eslint`? I can't find it in the docs :(

disallowKeywordsOnNewLine
Disallows placing keywords on a new line.

Type: Array

Values: Array of quoted keywords

Example

```
"disallowKeywordsOnNewLine": ["else"]
```

Valid

```
if (x < 0) {
    x++;
} else {
    x--;
}
```

Invalid

```
if (x < 0) {
    x++;
}
else {
    x--;
}
```

Maybe this option is not available in `eslint`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your looking for is `brace-style` in `eslint`.
Link: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/brace-style